# Should I pay for a certificate from a free online course?

Tags: resume, applications, certification

I am currently a student planning on entering the job market in 2-3 years, and I'm looking into some online courses relevant to my interests. I don't expect my current experience (astrophysics) to be *directly* relevant to a future employer, so I'm hoping to familiarize myself with the buzzword techniques of the business world. Most importantly, I expect to signal this extra-academia preparation to future employers down the road. 

Particularly in the case of [this machine learning course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning?authMode=signup) -- for which one can opt into a $79 fee for a "trusted, shareable certificate" -- **does the certificate of completion significantly increase one's chances of receiving an interview, as opposed to simply listing the course on a CV?**

The answer probably varies by field and individual business, but I'd like to know if these paid certificates are generally regarded as trivial or even if the certificate would *become* unimportant due to it being ~2 years old at the time of application.

---

**Update 2 years later:** I graduated with a Ph.D. in astrophysics and applied exclusively for data scientist positions in the months after graduation. Employers asked about my independent learning but never asked for certifications. Once I received their coding tests, the details of my learning were irrelevant to them; I received an offer for the position of senior data scientist at a U.S. manufacturing company, and it is going great. Best of luck to anyone reading this because they are considering a similar transition!

Comment: I have yet to meet a company that takes those kinds of certificates seriously. Stating that you completed the courses is more than enough. But that's just my experience.

Comment: Credentials, certifications, and stuff like that can't hurt your chances if they are current. But it's probably not a wise decision to get a cert (I'm guessing Coursera due to the cost) in a rapidly evolving field like ML that will be 2 years old by the time you get to show it off on a resume. Either get it closer to the time you will be entering the job market or get it now and plan on re-certifying yourself again right before going into the market.

Comment: You have electives.  Why not take machine learning courses?

Comment: @Paparazzi Because I can take an online course any time I want, at whatever pace I feel comfortable, without having to schedule time to get to a physical class, and without having to reason with my advisor that a course not immediately pertinent to my research might occasionally distract me from research. If I'm working a 60+ hour week, I'd like to have the option to ignore the online course for a moment.

Comment: @Sam Don't get your logic.  You have electives that are going to take your time.   An elective should be your elective.   A college course will carry weight.  An online course close to zero weight.   I managed to get a degree in engineering with more math credits if you count the engineering courses that were pure math.

Comment: @Paparazzi 1. As an elective it would meet no unfulfilled requirement, it would be purely for a transcript, unfortunately 2. I've wasted plenty of time taking interesting sounding courses that ended up being disappointing, and 3. I have sometimes had to shirk some elective responsibilities since I currently value my research and physics courses most. An overwhelmingly well reviewed online course solves these problems.

Comment: You have used all your electives with 2-3 years left? Purely for transcript has more value than any certificate. You don't seem to be in tune with machine learning more than it is a buzz word.

Comment: @Paparazzi Your criticisms all rest firmly on faulty assumptions about my education. Nothing I have told you is incorrect, and I have been using methods which fall into the umbrella of "machine learning" for several years in physics research. I have been warned by others who left for industry that my experiences with "big data" and "machine learning" -- however valid and in-depth -- may be misunderstood by employers, and that it would be good to familiarize myself with the terms and context in which _they_ use these terms.

Comment: All I can say is good luck.  If you think it takes an online course to familiarize with terms then more power to you.  What does terms have to do with certificate on a resume?  Again good luck.

Comment: Basically I've heard these kinds of interview horror stories from ex-colleagues.
1. They are asked about some really broad topic like "machine learning", and the interviewee seems flustered because the question seems so vague (like "what do you know about math?").

Comment: 2. The interviewee assumes they have no experience with machine learning because academics don't call it by this name. Later, the interviewee finds out that "machine learning" is an industry blanket term for all of the stats and coding they did during 6 years of PhD work.

Comment: 3. The interviewee has prepared for this, and goes into great detail how they used machine learning in their research. The interviewer becomes confused, because the interviewer is only familiar with one of the many branches of what is referred to as "machine learning".

Comment: @Paparazzi It's been suggested to me that these online courses are a good resource to become aware of all of these definitions and their contexts. I couldn't care less about some stupid certificate, *unless* it matters to employers, in which case I _must_ care about it.

Comment: You are using the methods but need an online course  become aware of all of these definitions and their contexts?  Again good luck.

Comment: what a gem you are to update this question!

Comment: @bharal Thank whomever viewed it for the 1kth time, SE for notifying me, and paparazzo for intentionally inflaming my sense of impostor syndrome so I'd remember to reassure folks facing similar post-graduation crises. ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**In my experience**, no. I completed some courses on Coursera and simply listed the names of the courses that I had completed. Nobody asked for proof, and if they did I would tell them the truth - that I considered it a waste of money to pay $79 for a certificate *after* having learned everything in the course.

Comment: I would have saved the HTML/made a screenshot of the "congrats, you passed" screen. Sure, it could be faked, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: Btw, is there a time limit on when you can pay this $79? I.e within X weeks of ending the course? Or can you just wait, and if an employer demands to see it, pay the $79 then?

Answer (score 4):

Coursera cracks me up with their sleight of hand with terminology. People talk about certifications and here's Coursera (or anyone else who does that) hawking a slightly different sounding product. It's not illegal but it's pretty close to snake oil.

What is a certificate?

> a document attesting to the fact that a person has completed an educational course, issued either by an institution not authorized to grant diplomas, or to a student not qualifying for a diploma.

The problem with certificates is that they're only as good as a) the one issuing them and b) the prestige of having one.  The simple fact is that **anyone** can issue a certificate. And because of that, they don't have any cachet or prestige. None.

What *can* have prestige is certifications. Certifications can be "just issued" but if you tell people that you have a certification that nobody respects, you'll get laughed at. Certifications from respected companies typically are based on test results and can often (though not always) demonstrate that you at least have a certain amount of knowledge in that area because they respect the company that issues it and the company doesn't want it to be just a useless piece of paper.

**TL;DR:**  Save your money. List that you took them if you'd like but nobody's going to want to see certificates. It's better that you can demonstrate that you have the knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Years ago, I listed Brainbench exam scores on my resume to make my skill level more obvious.  The word "certificate" itself might be bogus, but if you can show numbers that demonstrate you've tested out in a high percentile of test-takers, I think it can go a long way for you.  People like *numbers*.